# SQLAlchemy on Apple Mac M1

Tags: sql, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, apple-m1

What's the recommended way to access Microsoft SQL Server on an Apple Mac M1 using python in a jupyter notebook?

pymssql works ok, but sql.io complains about its preference for SQLAlchemy

bcpy works ok

pyodbc.drivers is empty

SQLAlchemy does not seem to work

No doubt paths are mucked up here.  Has anyone worked out the solution?

Comment: I can't find the MSSSQL driver in pyodbc.  pyodbc.drivers() is empty []

Comment: pymssql is not quite as dead as it once appeared to be. If pymssql works to your satisfaction then you could use `create_engine("mssql+pymssql://…")`

Comment: You're right, @GordThompson . Looks like that confirmed this [on 2 Apr](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/668#issuecomment-1086681292).